# Spatial search for neighbor with distance limit?

Tags: spatial, spatial-index, tarantool

In the [example](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/wiki/R-tree-index-quick-start-and-usage) page it is shown how to do a neighbor search with a limit on the number of returned items. Is it possible to also specify a distance limit? I.e.:

> Return all items that are at most X distance from the point, and further limit the result to Y number of items."

Answer (score 2):

No, if you need distance, use OVERLAPS.
https://tarantool.org/doc/book/box/box_index.html#rtree-iterator

Comment: Does it also work with points(zero width and height rectangle)? I.e. will all points contained in the search rectangle be returned?

Comment: You can try to use Tarantool GIS for that https://tarantool.github.io/gis/